# What is best approach of Replacement of AsyncTaskLoader by RxJava2?

Tags: android, rx-android, asynctaskloader, rx-java2

I am super junior in RxJava and I may need to find a better approach if there is a better way to do it.

I am working on a legacy `Loader` code and I want to replace it by RxJava. I have following in my original code:

```
public class CurrentBookingLoaderManager extends AsyncTaskLoader<Booking> {
    ...

    @Override
    public Booking loadInBackground() {
        try {
            return createPendingBookingObserver().blockingGet(); // Gets last Booking from back-end
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.logCaughtException(e);
            return loadPendingBookingFromDB();
        }
    }

    private Single<Booking> createPendingBookingObserver() {...}

    private Booking loadPendingBookingFromDB() {...}
}
```

So, My Presenter class is looking for latest Booking object in order to direct user to next screen (based on status of Booking).

```
final class Presenter {
    void findLatestBooking() {
        CurrentBookingLoaderManager.newInstance(mContext)
                .getPendingBooking(mActivity, new CurrentBookingLoaderManager.OnPendingBooking() {
                    @Override
                    public void found(Booking booking) {
                        ...
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Back to `CurrentBookingLoaderManager`, I created an interface and few methods in order to refactor the functionality of `loadInBackground()` in Rx way.

```
    public interface OnPendingBooking {
        void found(Booking booking);
    }

    public void getPendingBooking(final MyActivity activity, final OnPendingBooking callback) {
        CurrentBookingLoaderManager.newInstance(activity)
                .createPendingBookingObserver()
                .compose(activity.<Booking>asyncCallWithinLifecycle())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<Booking>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Booking booking) throws Exception {
                        callback.found(booking);
                    }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                        loadPendingBookingFromDB(activity, callback);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void loadPendingBookingFromDB(final MyActivity activity, final OnPendingBooking callback) {
        Single.fromCallable(new Callable<Booking>() {
            @Override
            public Booking call() throws Exception {
                return loadPendingBookingFromDB();
            }
        })
                .compose(activity.<Booking>asyncCallWithinLifecycle())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<Booking>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Booking booking) throws Exception {
                        callback.found(booking);
                    }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                        callback.found(null);
                    }
                });
    }
```

What makes me feel this is not right approach is having many many lines by using RxJava while Rx normally reduces number of lines of code. Might there be a better way to do it?

This code works fine based on my tests.

Comment: Rxjava 1 or 2? there is a little bit difference in classes in both.

Comment: @Saurabh RxJava 2 actually, thanks for asking :) I just updated my question.

Comment: the only thing you could improve is using `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` , instead of creating a new thread everytime. rest looks fine to me. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. [RetroLambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda)
2. [SqlBrite](https://github.com/square/sqlbrite) instead of AsyncTaskLoader
3. If possible [Realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-java) instead of sqlite.
4. `subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())` -> `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` (no need to create new thread each time)
5. And

   ```
   Observable
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   ```

Can be replaced with

```
public class RxUtil {

    public static <T> Observable.Transformer<T, T> applySchedulers() {
        return observable -> observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }
}
```

and

```
Observable
   .compose(RxUtil::applySchedulers)
```

Comment: Thanks for your points. Unfortunately I cannot overhaul the structure of the app :(

Comment: How does it handle configuration change (like changing orientation) ?

Comment: Offline first approach and no need to handle anything - all state will be in DB